# Images won't show up in javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Images won't show up in javascript slideshow, I've been working on this for three days now and I'm sick of it. I've even started to cheat and just copy other sliders I've seen online (open source) and use those. This is for work, please help me.

```
<div id="slideshow" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="slideshowimage" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
  </div>
  <div id="slideshowcontrols" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
    <a onClick="alterimage(-1);">Prev</a>
    <a onClick="alterimage(1);">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = new Array;
    images[1] = "Images/image1.jpg";
    images[2] = "Images/image2.jpg";
    images[3] = "Images/image3.jpg";
    var presentimage = 1;
    function alterimage(alter){
        presentimage += alter;
        document.getElement('slideshow').innerHTML = presentimage;
    }
    alterimage(0);
</script>
```

Comment: What isn't working?  What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: It seems like you're changing the content of the wrong tag ("slideshow" rather than "slideshowimage") with the wrong content (presentimage, which is just a counter, rather than, say, an IMG tag with the SRC set to images[presentimage]).

Comment: Oh, and as mentioned in one of the answers, you're also using the wrong command to fetch the tag element. It should be getElementById.

Comment: You aren't using the images after you've assigned them to places in your array.  Like Eran said, you are setting the `innerHTML` of `slideshow` to that `presentimage` counter.  You should be setting those image paths in your array as an attribute to an `img` tag inside the `slideshowimage` div.  Also, `getElement` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function as `getElement`, it should be `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = presentimage;
```

Comment: What is not working? The images won't show? You need to put an image tag in there and change the source.

Comment: This isn't going to work as I think the goal is to have images in the slideshow, not just the filenames. Please @user3071842 check out my updated answer, I believe that's what you are after!

Comment: Well, it solves OP's problem.. OP has to replace the pseudo code with actual code for the images.

Comment: "Images won't show up in javascript slideshow" Nope, it won't solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there...

I've found a few things in your code and I have fixed them:

- There isn't `document.getElement` but `document.getElementById('id')`
- You won't have a slideshow without images, so I added the `<img>` tag.
- Use CSS classes for styling instead of inline styling, it is a lot more readable and easier to maintain.

Here is my updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/jWLZz/10/

I had to alter the code quite a bit to make it work - and to make it easier to read:

- I altered the DOM by removing the inline CSS and adding the styling through classes
- I added the `<img>` tag, so that you can have images instead of just their names
- I added proper JavaScript event handlers to both the `<a>` tags
- I updated the JavaScript function, so now it swaps the image source of the image tag once you click on the previous or next links.

And just as a suggestion, I would not start filling up my arrays from index 1 but 0 to keep up with the way arrays work in JavaScript.

I also added the code bits to my answer below, I hope it all makes sense.

Updated HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
    <img id="slideshowimage"/>

    <div id="slideshowcontrols" class="slideshow">
        <a href='#' class='prev-link'>Prev</a>
        <a href='#' class='next-link'>Next</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Updated JavaScript:

```
var images = new Array;
images[0] = "http://placekitten.com/200/100";
images[1] = "http://placekitten.com/300/200";
images[2] = "http://placekitten.com/200/200";
var presentimage = 0;

document.getElementsByClassName('next-link')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alterimage(1);
});
document.getElementsByClassName('prev-link')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alterimage(-1);
});

var alterimage = function alterimage(alter){
    presentimage += alter;
    document.getElementById('slideshowimage').setAttribute('src', images[presentimage]);
}
alterimage(0);
```

Comment: Actually, I realised that there are more issues with your code. 1: You don't have an image element in your DOM; 2: You're not setting the source of that element once the alterimage method is called. I am updating the Fiddle just now...

Comment: There probably is a lot wrong with it, I abandoned the one I was working on and just started copy and pasting a bunch of others I found hoping one would eventually work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're not accessing the images stored in your array, you just set the `innerHTML` of the slideshow `div` to your counter.  I added an empty `img` tag to the slideshowimage `div`.  The `src` attribute of that `img` tag is then set to the corresponding image url in the array when you pass and array index through the `alterimage` function.

```
<div id="slideshow" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="slideshowimage" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
         <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshowcontrols" style="width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
        <a onClick="alterimage(-1);">Prev</a>
        <a onClick="alterimage(1);">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = new Array;
    images[0] = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png";
    images[1] = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo10w.png";
    images[2] = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    var presentimage = 0;

   function alterimage(alter){
       presentimage += alter;
       document.getElementById('slideshowimage').childNodes[1].setAttribute('src',
       images[presentimage]);
   }
    alterimage(2);
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lrrpu/